# Buttons become unclickable after certain actions - how to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

1 – I have a search and filter form on my mobile site (480px and below) made with Search and Filter Pro plugin. Here’s the screenshot showing what I mean: 
[image] 
 If you click on “Pokaż filtry” filters will appear. The problem is that when you expand it and just click “filtruj” (filter), the “Pokaż filtry” button will stop working – you can click as many times as you want but it won’t expand anymore (it becomes unclickable). Everything will start working again after refresh.

2. Second problem is very similar to the first one. At 480px and below, when you choose any option and click “filtruj” the whole search form will dissapear. Everything will start working fine again after refresh.
3. At resolution 960px to 480px there’s a button to show sidebar. 
   [image] 
   There’s also a Search and Filter form. When you use it, you can’t close the sidebar – the button just stops working (becomes unclickable).

These issues are 100% caused by Search and Filter Pro plugin. When I deactivate it, everything works fine. Most likely it's a conflict with theme.

Here's my site - http://gromocje.pl/

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it? I feel like I tried everything... I've never seen such a issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.otfm-sp__title').click(function() {
```

replace with:

```
$(document).on('click', '.otfm-sp__title', function() {
```

Reference & more info - [stackoverflow.com/a/29674985/2245806](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29674985/2245806)

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me in which file should I change it? I can't find it

Comment: My advice is not to do that, better add own script: [link](https://pastebin.com/HhdSwFJE)

Comment: BTW file is http://gromocje.pl/wp-content/plugins/otfm-gutenberg-spoiler/res/otfm-spoiler-min.js

Comment: Sorry for a silly question, but where exactly should I add the code?

Comment: I added it but unfortunately it's even worse than it was before. After injecting that script, the search and filter form on mobile (480px and below) is not clickable even after refreshing the site. No changes regarding the sidebar

Comment: I replaced the code in the plugin and #1 is fixed. Second and third problem still exists. I know that replacing the plugin code is not a perfect solution but if nothing else works then I will use it.

Comment: Can u provide Skype/Discord acc?

Comment: Sure! Discord: Kacper#8684